# What do you call the child who doesn’t resemble his / her parents in English?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are sons and daughters who don’t look like their parents at all. We call them “Onikko 鬼っ子” in Japanese, which literally means the child born or brought by an ogre, not by his / her biological parents.

Onikko doesn't necessarily mean derogatory. For instance, when we have a brilliant child brought up by mediocre parents, we describe the child 鳶が鷹を産んだ子 - tobi ga taka wo unda ko - a hawk born by a kite. The hawk (child) can be a kind of Onikko.

What is the expression in English for the son or daughter who doesn't resemble his / her parent in face, figure and temper though they are their parents' real child?

Comment: The postman/milkman/mailman?

Comment: @Ronan +1 Trust an Irishman!

Comment: I have to remember that Onikko thing :-D

Comment: Wow, those terms sound like a really mean thing to say.

Comment: Mustn't say "how do you call?" rather "what do you call?"

Comment: Tristan r. Thanks for your advice. I corrected the title. As Filippino questioner mentined in his question, we wont to confuse what and how, since we say "...をどう言うか- HOW do you say it?" in Japanese when we ask the name or word for the something. I'll be mindful of the distinction.

Comment: The glint in the milkman's eye (I created an account for this)

Comment: .............."adopted"

Comment: In my village, we call them `neighbors mistake`.

Comment: We call them ***children***.  And we move on.

Comment: Yoichi Oishi, that's a good point. English seems to be unusual in this regard, when compared to other languages.

Comment: never mind... deleted

Comment: @Tristanr: Actually, if he'd originally said 'how do you say...' it would have been fine. 言う is 'say' anyway. It's more a matter of the word 'call' not applying.

Comment: In the 1970s in western countries there were wife swapping parties that were called KEY PARTIES where car keys were placed in a bowl and randomly drawn to determine the prospective father .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Usually it would be polite not to mention the fact that a child doesn't seem to resemble its parents, since this might imply infidelity on the part of the mother (not good for Susan George in the 1975 film [Mandingo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073349/)). But you will sometimes encounter OED's sense 6a for...

> **sport** *- a  plant (or part of a plant), animal, etc., which exhibits abnormal or striking variation from the parent type, esp. in form or colour; a spontaneous mutation; a new variety produced in this way.*

This noun usage derives from the (now rare) *verb* sense...

> **sport** (v 8a) *- of nature (originally, personified): to ‘amuse herself’ or delight in producing the variety of things in existence, especially abnormal or striking living forms; to produce such forms.*

---

As @ronan comments, facetious *"He looks like the [postman](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22child%20is%20a%20sport%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22looks%20like%20the%20postman%22&tbm=bks) / [milkman](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22child%20is%20a%20sport%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22looks%20like%20the%20milkman%22&tbm=bks) / etc."* is not uncommon.

There's also **throwback** *(reversion to an earlier ancestral type or character; an example of this)*. But unless accompanied by a reference to a specific grandparent (or perhaps *great* grandparent) that the child *does* resemble, this invariably has negative associations (with the implicit unspecified ancestor being a Neanderthal or some other precursor to *homo sapiens*).

Comment: Great thinking on **throwback**, Fumble.  yoichi, that's the only term that specifically means **looks/is very different from the siblings** "She must be a throwback! Where did she get that beautiful red hair!"  "She's taller than all four sisters, must be a throwback!" "The rest are failing, but she's a straight A student, must be a throwback!"  **But Wait!**  Fumble, you say *throwback* is used for Onikko children. On the contrary I've only heard it used for tobi-ga-taka-wo-unda-ko children.

Comment: @Joe: As I understand it, *oniko* seems to be normally derogatory (unless the context implies ***alluringly** deviant*, as in "vampire girls are sexy"). Most Googled "Images" for "oniko child" have devil's horns. But [*Tonbi ga taka wo umu*](http://www.linguanaut.com/japanese_sayings.htm) (literally: *a kite breeding a hawk*) looks to be invariably complimentary (to the child, if not the parents! :). I'd only use *throwback* positively when referencing a specific revered ancestor, and even then you'd need to be careful of the far more common *negative* associations. But *sport* is "neutral".

Comment: Hi @fumble - yes I completely and utterly understand everything you said.  I may not have been clear.  You say, you'd only use *throwback* in a negative sense.  You imply you've only heard *throwback* used in a negative sense. What I'm telling you is that is not my experience at all.  (I am very surprised you report that.)  I've only ever heard *throwback* used in a highly positive sense. Notice my three examples in quotation marks.  (Cont...)

Comment: Note: "throwback" applies to humans for sure, and also animal breeders. I'm almost certain if you asked a thrgbred breeder what a "throwback" is, he'd say: well it's an awesome horse ("like in the old days") that arrived in a mediocre pair, and surely is a throwback to such-and-such incredible ancestor of the mare or stallion. I've certainly only EVER heard *throwback* used in the positive way for humans, and horses too. (As you mention out, HUMOROUSLY, you might say "throwback to the neandertals!")

Comment: @Joe: Well, I suppose if the context is such that both speaker and audience share a common perception that everything in the Garden of Eden was perfect, and that everything since then is "degenerate" (or more generally, "traditionalists" vs. "progressives"), *throwback* could be considered inherently positive. Personally, I don't believe in "noble savages" (so far as I'm concerned, the whole concept is misguided myth-making intended to drive "sinners" into the arms of quack Evangelists). So it doesn't work for me without the *explicitly-named* noble ancestor.

Comment: I've used the word changeling often enough. Heard it used often , too, regarding looks, temperament, other attributes. Usually intended with som humor.

Comment: I still remember that 'sport' was defined in exactly this way when I read *A Wrinkle In Time* long ago. I've honestly never heard any of the others mentioned here in person or in literature, in a similar context. In that book alone, two of the characters had the term applied to them in a fairly positive light.

Comment: @Magus: I haven't read *A Wrinkle In Time*, but I must admit I was also thinking of the sci-fi context for *sport = genetically inexplicable **human** offspring* (The Mule in Frank Herbert's *Dune*). In "ordinary conversation" I'd probably only use *sport* in respect of plants. But that's probably because if I was talking about an actual person (which per the first sentence in my answer would be unlikely! :) I'd probably want to "soften" the potential awkwardness by mentioning the postman/milkman instead.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The Mule in Dune ? You're sure you didn't mean Asimov's Foundation ? You've got keep the Classics straight :-)

Comment: The character who makes the comment in the book is a genius child who doesn't mind explaining it, and almost immediately applies it to himself as well. Because I first read the book at a young age, I've simply always assumed this was the correct word and that it was more well known. In any case, it's quite accurate. Also, @Tonny: it's especially odd considering that one of the major points in *Dune* is genetics generally working exactly as expected.

Comment: @Magus That struck me as well. I looked at Fumbles comment and knew something was odd about it. Took several seconds before it sank in what was wrong. It was so apt to the concept that my brain almost went along with it. (Not quite though, but that's probably because I just finished a re-read of the entire Dune series just 2 weeks ago. It's still very fresh.)

Comment: @Tonny: Eeek! You're quite right, of course! There was I thinking senility was something I could look forward to, but it turns out to have already arrived!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess now I know why you use the nick FumbleFingers :-)

Comment: @Tonny: Yeah - both the digits *and* the ole grey matter are definitely getting a bit past their prime (and neither of them were ever *that* good in the first place! :)

Comment: unicorn‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Comment: I weighed adaptability of ‘changeling’ ‘milk / postman,’ and ‘sport’ to the Japanese concept of ‘Onikko,’ who is not a replacement, but a real child of biological parents.  ‘Changeling’ and ‘milk /postman’ don’t seem to fit to in this regard. To me ‘sport’ looks closer to ‘Onikko,’ provided it isn’t used derogatorily. OALD defines ‘sport’ “a plant or an animal that is different in a noticeable way from its usual type.” ‘Onikko’ is “a child that looks different in a noticeable way from its real parents.”

Comment: Hi @Fumble, *"So it doesn't work for me without the explicitly-named noble ancestor"*...  I find your comments extremely confusing.  I completely understand your comments on traditionalists, etc - but, who cares? (Heh!)  The point at hand is **common usage**.  **You have asserted** that you have heard it used in a negative way. To me, that is extremely strange. I have heard it used many, many times - but only in a **positive** way. To be absolutely clear. **Have you heard it used* by someone (with your ears) in a negative way?

Comment: Thus, "this invariably has negative associations..." that passage is wrong.  It's not complicated: Exactly as it is commonly used with horse breeders, "throwback" is used regarding humans in a sentence like this: "wow, she's so tall and good looking, must be a throwback"  "they all have mousy hair but she has that striking platinum hair, must be a throwback!"

Comment: "Garden of Eden.." it's plain weird that you see "throwback" as relating to hundreds of generations, dude.  the word is just used for grandparents or "distant" (ie, 3 to 6 say) generations.  (Example, I was reading a discussion re. winston churchill, and a comment along the lines "his excellence was a throwback to his great uncle Lord XYZ...") By all means, "throwback" is used in scientific evolutionary, genetic, discussions, but then you're talking species-like time frames (1000s or 10000s generations?)

Answer (score 39):

You could use **the/an apple that fell far from the tree**.

This is a play on the saying "The apple doesn't fall far from the tree", meaning that children tend to resemble their parents both physically as well as temperamentally, or even in more mundane aspects such as job choice or favourite football team.

By saying it this way, you leave it up to the listener (or to context) to decide where the difference between child and parent lies and whether the difference is a positive or negative one.

Comment: This is a really good one. Not only it's without any negative connotations of adultery, it actively reinforces the opposite. Really nice.

Comment: Note that "The apple doesn't fall far from the tree" is, I'd say, **usually used only negatively**, specifically about criminal behaviour.

Comment: "different" or "lone" or "black sheep of the family" or "variant" (scientific) or.. ummm.. genetic malfunction? :) seriously, just brainstorming on the spot.. donkey's calf or cow's pup? or he's like "water in the desert" or "burning ice"? uh-huh the latter could have negative connotations.. and so forth :) everything doesn't have to be set in stone my friend.. go against the norms even if you know not if they don't exist :) cheers!

Comment: the most crude way to say it is bastard. foundling or orphan doesn't hold true for at least 1 parent. bastard has at least the mother in the picture. the child could have been fathered by a man outside the mother's marriage; and hence look peculiar

Comment: @EffectorDhanushanth: It sounds to me like the question is about a genetic oddity rather than infidelity. Adding that connotation at all does not fit with the question, which mentions a child who does not resemble the 'real parents'.

Comment: Isn't this phrase used more often in reference to behavior or personality, rather than appearance?

Answer (score 20):

For the temperament side, I've seen "changeling", a reference to the medieval belief that children were sometimes stolen by fairies and replaced by imperfect magical copies. I've never heard a term for children who don't look like their parents short of technical terms such as "outlier" and, of course, the occasional term that implies that they were fathered by someone else entirely.

Comment: +1 - some sources also state that the natural child was exchanged for an *ugly* one.

Comment: I'm perfectly familiar with *changeling* from archaic fairy stories, but I'm not convinced I've even heard it used *facetiously* in contemporary English. I'm quite certain I've never heard it used "naturally" in a conversational context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've heard it in conversation here in Pittsburgh (probably helps that I've got a number of acquaintances into new age fairy-based paganism *shudder*), but it's not exactly common, I'll agree. Personally, I think that your submission, "sport," is a better word overall.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - I've heard it commonly as well, and I'm not into anything new-agey. Just well read, and plenty of stories read to the children.

Comment: @Sean: I'm not sure what to make of that. Do you mean your latter-day "pagan" friends use the term because they actually believe supernatural forces were involved? Or that they think whoever they're *talking* to is so daft as to believe such an explanation, rather than the (far more likely) one of *infidelity on the part of the mother?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Honestly, I wonder sometimes. I *think* that they're using it playfully, but I've learned a long time ago to never assume someone's religious belief is a joke because far too often, they're dead serious.

Comment: @Sean: I guess it takes all sorts to make a world, but I think if anyone seriously believed fairies, trolls, elves, or whatever might be responsible for a child not resembling its parents, I'd say that person was a loony-tunes fruitcake, rather than ["Religious, but not as we know it, Jim"](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2325035/Its-Star-Trek-Jim-know-Unearthed-writers-guide-reveals-best-intentions-casual-sexism-iconic-1960s-TV-show.html)

Comment: it's inconceivable anyone would use the term "changeling", in English, for what the OP is asking.  it's just totally unrelated.  "outlier" could indeed be used, in describing the situation, but it's not in any way a term used for it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Joe Blow, Changeling was my first thought too, and the term I would probably use. You don't have to believe in fairies, or that the child has come from the milkman, in order to use those terms.There are 2 films called [The] Changeling, so it's by no means an obscure term.  On the other hand, 'sport' appears to be technically correct, but have you heard it used in this way? I never have. I would opt for any other answer here, including 'throwback', but never 'sport'.

Comment: @Mynamite: I don't think any native speakers are suggesting *changeling* is an "obscure" word. But if you consider, say, [Sandra Laing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandra_Laing) (black woman born of white parents), I think few if any competent speakers would refer to her as a *changeling*. That Wikipedia article does in fact use *throwback*. I agree *sport* (more closely associated with plants) is perhaps a bit too "dehumanising" for such a sensitive context - but to me at least, it's better than figurative *changeling* with its credulous medieval associations.

Comment: @JoeBlow: I've seen *changeling* used to suggest more generally that the child is unlike the rest of the family in some way, though it can refer to differences in personality rather than appearance.  I recall seeing it in some Agatha Christie novels, for instance.  I can find citations if you'd like.

Comment: @Mynamite: Changeling includes 'change' which implies to some extent that the subject can do so. Even if you only apply this to temperament, it sounds almost entirely negative to me. It definitely implies that the subject is not genuine. I wouldn't apply that to a human.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think, like so many questions on this site, that it all comes down to context. With the child of friends who I knew would not be offended, I would definitely use 'changeling', teasingly. I agree it would not be appropriate in a tragic case like Sandra Laing's.

Comment: @Mynamite: You will obviously use whatever word seems suitable to you, but I must just say that historically/etymologically, *changeling* has nothing to do with the "subject's ability to change". The allusion is to the idea that mythical beings (elves, trolls, fairies) ***exchanged*** the human baby for an [eldritch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eldritch) one of their own.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you're mixing me up with Magus, I never said anything about the subject's ability to change :)

Comment: @Mynamite: My bad. But I do note that you qualified your *I would definitely use 'changeling'* with ***teasingly***. That doesn't seem unreasonable to me, but I am somewhat surprised that several people are apparently claiming they would use it "non-facetiously". To me it's just an antiquated jocular alternative to *milkman/postman* allusions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well.. yes and no. The milkman/postman allusion, and others like 'cuckoo', suggest infidelity whereas 'changeling' does not. As for antiquated/believing in fairies etc, the OP refers to 'child brought by an ogre'. Surely changeling is more in line with that idea? For 'antiquated' I'd rather say 'traditional', rooted in heritage.

Comment: @Mynamite: That's what baffles me. I don't see how anyone can simultaneously say *'changeling' doesn't imply infidelity* ***and*** it's a valid non-facetious usage ***and*** it doesn't imply belief in supernatural intervention. But I do note that [*a changeling child*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+changeling+child&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20changeling%20child%3B%2Cc0) has only gained currency in AmE in the last century, so perhaps it's kinda "divorced" from the original medieval usage and connotations.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Am finding it hard to understand why you think those things are exclusive. It definitely does not imply infidelity. It does not imply a belief in the supernatural any more than saying 'Oh my God!' when you hear startling news implies that you are Christian. Do Japanese people believe in ogres? And it *could* be facetious in some circumstances (Sandra Laing) but how often does that situation arise? Aren't we more likely to be discussing the child of friends/family/neighbours? It all depends on intention, whether you're being affectionate or purposefully bitching.

Comment: @Mynamite: I don't think you're grasping my point. To me, *changeling* isn't a "figurative" usage where I could reasonably ignore the "original" sense. It's not in the same category as, for example, talking about [a gifted child](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+gifted+child%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) who has [been blessed with](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22has+been+blessed+with%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) some remarkable talent. Neither of which figurative usages put me much in mind of supernatural beings conferring favour. Those are just "idioms".

Answer (score 14):

How about, "The baby was switched at the hospital." Or, as I like to say when asked why my brother and I don't look anything alike, "Our mothers were switched at the hospital."

Comment: That is an **outstanding suggestion**. That's really the only thing I can think of like this in English, that is really close to what Yoichi is asking.  **GREAT THINKING**.  "Switched at birth" is the short version of the same thing.  "Look at her compared to her sisters, must have been switched at birth!"  that **precisely means, 'very different from siblings'**.  GREAT ANSWER.

Answer (score 13):

While I'm not a native speaker, I'd like to offer **cuckoo**, or maybe **cuckoo child**. Cuckoos are well-known to be obligate brood parasites, laying their eggs in the nests of other birds, relying on them to raise their offspring. John Wyndham uses this word in a similar sense in the title of his novel [The Midwich Cuckoos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Midwich_Cuckoos).

Alternatively, taking a step back, how about **the oddball of the family**, or even (a bit satirically) **the black sheep of the family**? For example: *John, descendant of a long line of parish priest, became the black sheep of the family when he became an accountant.*

I believe these alternatives would not be so horribly offensive in an everyday context.

Comment: +1 for black sheep. It's often used figuratively to describe behavior or life choices (as in your example), but the more literal sense of "Doesn't look like all the other sheep" fits well for the question. "How did your son happen to have green eyes?" "We're not sure, he's the black sheep of the family."

Comment: While we're de-anthropomorphising, **ugly duckling** seems to fit the bill.

Comment: Hey Edwin -- seems unrelated? Ugly duckling means "looks ugly when young, but surprisingly turns out extremely hot".  I don't see any relationship to the "the postman did it!" concept "different from siblings/parents."

Comment: Cuckoo wouldn't be a good term to use, because **cuckolded** is indeed the technical term for when a wife cheats on her husband and fathers a child with another man (the "postman..." thing!)  This seems different to what Yoichi is asking.  (Although it could _result_ in that!)  By the way on the subject of cuckolding, I recommend the amaxing scientific textbook, "Human Sperm Competition: Copulation, Masturbation and Infidelity." by Baker and Bellis.

Comment: The Hungarian term for this "one of these things is not like the others, one of these things just doesn't belong" concept is *kakukktojás* "cuckoo's egg". There is a whiff of "cuckold" behind it, but that is not the primary meaning.

Comment: "Cuckoo child" doesn't exist in English, and wouldn't be understood. The slang meaning of "cuckoo" in English is "crazy", not "interloper".

Answer (score 6):

Later: **runt of the litter**

Yoichi, I finally thought of a common phrase somewhat like what you say.  Well for an Onikko, not the other one. If you are the **shortest** sibling, schoolyard language might be "he's the runt of the litter."

This is not exactly like Onikko -- but it is one subset of Onikko!

In certain circumstances, if you were translating a minor character in a novel, you could get away with "runt of the litter" as a quick substitution.

("Runt" is simply the word for an undersized farm animal (say, a pig) or the smallest (say, pig) in a litter. When you use it for a human, it's mildly derogatory, mildly comic.)

---

In my opinion, there's really **nothing for this in English**.

(I was fascinated to learn the Japanese terms - thanks for that!)

{By the way. This is a great concrete example of how Japanese (and many other languages) are incredibly less "politically correct" that today's English.}

One thing comes to mind:

**"red-headed stepchild"** is an unusual often-used derogatory term for - not so much exactly what you ask - but a child that is treated badly, or is really "excluded from" the family, let's say. (A little like, say, *Cinderella* in the story.)  It is highly derogatory (or else, just used wildly humorously), and it is wildly offensive to both red-headed people and adoptees  :)  So don't use it  :)

**black sheep** is not, really, close to what you're asking, it's more one who is well, a bad person in an otherwise straight family (or used in lighter ways, example all the other siblings get high marks in school)

Regarding the references to **postman** and similar. If you're wondering what the hell we're talking about...

It is a low-quality standing joke in English that if a child's father is not the mother's husband -- ie, she cheated on him -- then the father was "the postman" or "milkman".  indeed, anytime you see someone who does NOT resemble their father, many people would make a low-quality joke regarding "the milkman".  For example, they might snicker and whisper "Heh, the postman has been busy around here..."

(That type of humour very much makes me think of [Benny Hill(http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benny_Hill) and the "low quality" British TV humour of the 1970ish, such as the "Carry On..." series.)

{It would be staggeringly hard to explain the "Carry On..." series to someone from Japan, if you're not familiar with it. :) }

{Example: we had a TV series in that time period called "Are you being served?" which is set in a department store. (The title is a (incredibly lame) sexual innuendo.) Now, one of the characters had a cat at home. In English you can call a cat a "pussy", and that is also a slang term for vagina. Now, almost ***the entire content*** of the show was based on "pussy" being a pun with vagina. So, the lady in question would say "my pussy was so hungry today," "my pussy really needs a wash" and so on and on and on. ... !  honestly, that was sort of 70% of the entire comic content of the show :) }

Anyway, my point is that the **"postman..."** reference from the snickering Lads above, was rather in that "Benny Hill" "Carry on.." sort of poor-quality British humour of the 1970s.

{Note that, confusingly, shortly after this in the UK we/they had on TV incredibly subtle, outstanding, upper-class intellectual comedy - heh!  For example *to the manor born* {in this case the title is an exceedingly fine play on words} which contained an unending stream of absolutely amazingly subtle humour in English, eg., Audrey points to a fireplace and says "antiques, He wouldn't know it from Adam."}

Bottom line - there's no term for that in English.

---

Note - Fumble brilliantly thought of *throwback*.

That's not a *term for* Onikko or tobi-ga-taka-wo-unda-ko.

But it's very often used, exclaimed, when you see or are talking about a tobi-ga-taka-wo-unda-ko.

{For example. if we did in fact use the word tobi-ga-taka-wo-unda-ko in English, you'd hear "Wow, she is such a tobi-ga-taka-wo-unda-ko - must be a throwback a few generations!"}

(Note however that Fumble asserts it's for Onikko, me, I've only ever heard it used for tobi-ga-taka-wo-unda-kos.)

Comment: whoops, *Are you being served?* was more around late 70s - but there's still some intellectual point to be made there in the arc of Brit comedy TV. You had a final sort of superb cultural flowering, until everything dissolved into ladettes vomiting on the bus stop and later baroque phases of dissolution such as "that olympics opening thing" etc.

Comment: Fumble also suggested 'sport', which *is* actually the term in English for this concept.

Comment: You interpret this an example of Japanese being "incredibly less politically correct" than English, but I can also see it as the opposite. Many responses here immediately jump to thinking of infidelity on the part of the woman, whereas the Japanese are comfortable talking of the simple fact of nature that children do not always resemble their parents in every respect (in "face, figure and temper" as the OP says), without any implicit innuendo about infidelity. (The OP seems to have needed to add "though they are their parents' real child" to the question, having not thought of it before.)

Comment: Hi @Shree!  (1) you completely misunderstand me. You think I mean it is P.I. because there is an implication of infidelity. Not at all. It is incredibly P.I. to say **a child is brought by an ogre**.  Simple. And the other one ("your parents are useless mediocre kite birds") is extremely P.I. Also simple :)  (2) "Many responses here immediately jump to infidelity.." not at all, it's been pointed out over and over (starting with the OP) that infidelity is specifically what is **not** meant.  (3) I believe your tenor is politically correct :) IMO, Japan is much less PC than US/UK/Aus.

Comment: @JoeBlow: No I didn't misunderstand you, and I wasn't thinking that. I was pointing out that, just as western people seem to think that of appearance or ability is "politically incorrect", but their minds freely wander to infidelity, the Japanese may be the opposite. It's just a matter of which aspects a culture decides are taboo; it's not a matter of one being unequivocally "less PC" than the other.

Comment: There is an artist named Todd Goldman whose work is rather simplistic but I saw his milkman ["who's your daddy"](http://ep.yimg.com/ay/gallerydirectart/todd-goldman-handsigned-and-numbered-limited-edition-lithograph-on-paper-whos-your-daddy-3.jpg) at a gallery in LA and it just cracks me up for some reason.  Funny to read this and think about how many people would look at that and go "I don't get it."  :-)

Comment: **runt** _n._ **1.** a stunted or undersized animal, plant, thing, or (usually in a contemptuous sense) person **2.** the smallest animal of a litter  (Webster's NewWorld Dictionary, 2nd concise ed.)  But granted, it's not much worse than black sheep or ugly duckling.

Comment: ugly duckling has no connection whatsoever, in any way.

Answer (score 3):

LM Montgomery refers to a child who doesn't resemble other family members as a
*[hop out of kin](http://rainbow-valley.t.ebooks2ebooks.com/12.html)*. That's probably pretty archaic and overly idiomatic for what you're looking for, though.

Comment: This is the technically best answer. If only the word were more popular.

Answer (score 2):

The word you're looking for is [xenogenesis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/xenogenesis?s=t), so xenogenic perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

My wife and I have just such a child. He's blonde with grey-blue eyes, and my wife and I are both brunette and have hazel eyes, so the lack of resemblance is *really* obvious. But no, there really isn't any widely-known word for this. "Recessive genes" would be good explanation (and true, he gets these traits from one of my uncles).

There is however, a widely-known cultural joke for this phenomenon, and it's in one of the comments. "He comes from the milkman/mailman", said with a nudge and a wink. Using the word "milkman" specifically is especially coy, since milkmen just don't exist anymore, and haven't for some 40 or 50 years. When my wife says he comes from the mailman, I like to respond "but our mailman was a girl!" Any shocked looks get followup explanations about the recessive genes brought to our family by my uncle.

From now on though, I'm going to start calling him our Onikko. The English language is certainly *not* above stealing terms and grammar from other languages. ;)

It's pronounced "oh-NEEK-oh" right?

Comment: Milkmen do still exist [citation pending].

Comment: In Japanese it's pronounced "oni-kko"in all short vowel. 'Oni' means Ogre. "Ko" means a child. But you can pronounce in your own way, as we pronounce 'milk' 'miruku,''handkerchief' 'hankachi' in Japanese. It's up to you how to adopt foreign language.

Comment: Yoichi - we're not like that in English-speaking areas.  We want to be told the CORRECT way to do something  :)

Answer (score 1):

The word *atavistic* is an adjective, which means to resemble ones ancestors, and is normally used when it appears that a person doesn't resemble a parent, and often there might be a mention of a grandparent, or even beyond. The noun is *atavism*. It's not quite the same as the word you have in Japanese for them, or it wouldn't quite convey the same meaning, or even sound right, if you said "He is an ativism"; because it sounds too formal and it isn't as colourful.

The adverb *atavistically* is useful in less formal usage. You could say something like "His appearance was atavistically unlike his parents. Using the adverb here in this way would not sound impolite as it hints at a former generation, and it doesn't sound like there is a suspicion that it was the milkman. (Oh damn, I even fell into that trap too.)

Comment: "Atavism" is the state of being atavistic. Someone who is atavistic is an *atavist*, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

We don't really have anything like this in English. The closest is "black sheep", which refers to someone different from the rest of the family, but usually in temperament, not appearance.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no single word for this.  You could refer to the child as being the reincarnation of someone he or she reminds you of.  This would work well as a compliment.  For example, a child who is a musical prodigy might be a "reincarnation of Mozart." "Switched at birth" is also commonly used, e.g. "I don't know where he gets that blond hair from; I think he must have been switched at birth."  Personally, I often call my own child "demon spawn," but I think most parents would be offended if someone said that to them.  This would typically be used to describe a child who is misbehaving, but also indicates that the child's behavior is not the parents' fault.

The "milkman's child" specifically refers to a child who does not resemble the father.  It indicates adultery.

Just a note: the term "sport" is not used in the aforementioned way in the U.S., so consider location before you choose a phrase.  A little more context might help you get a more appropriate answer.  (I am new to this site, so I am not able to comment directly on the posts mentioning "sport.")

Comment: Certainly, *sport* indeed has the sense given by a different answer in the US, even if you were previously unaware of it.  And you should not comment on other answers in your own.